# Who coined the term "(Non)Derogatory Matrices"?

Tags: matrices, math-history

In a lecture, there was the question upcoming who coined the term
"nonderogatory". I tried to search for it a bit, but the earliest I found so far was by Charles G. Cullen in 1990, which seems not likely.

So the question is:

> Who coined/defined the term
>   "Nonderogatory Matrices" / "Derogatory Matrices"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.368.9837&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article by [Nick Higham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Higham), [Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joseph_Sylvester) introduced the term *derogatory matrix*.

[This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2027370) other article also mentions Sylvester, namely an article he wrote in the french *Comptes rendus de l'Académie des sciences* *(v.98, I (1884), pp. 471-475)*, which can be found on Gallica, [here](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k30546/f464.image). It starts with:

> Avant de considérer l'équation $xy=yx$, il importe d'avoir une idée nette d'une certaine classe de matrices que je nomme *privilégiées* ou *dérogatoires*, en tant qu'elles dérogent à la loi générale que toute matrice est assujettie à satisfaire à une équation identique dont le degré ne peut pas être moindre que l'ordre de la matrice.

A rough translation could be

> Before considering the equation $xy=yx$, it's necessary to consider a certain class of matrices I call *privileged* or *derogatory*, in that they derogate from the general rule that a matrix satisfies an equation whose degree cannot be less than the order of the matrix.

Comment: I will keep the question open for a few more hours and if there aren't any other answers I will accept it. Thank you for your work.